# How to get workspace path in Eclipse Plugin project?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an Eclipse plugin project and I'm trying to get the path of the workspace the project is running in. (not the path of the plugin's workspace)
All what I found is the following code which gives the workspace of the plugin:

```
String url = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toString();
```

Is there any way to get the path of the current workspace (and not the workspace of the plugin)?

Comment: Sorry don't understand, there is only one one workspace.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "the external workspace"; can you clarify with examples of what you're seeing and what you expect to see?

Comment: Your edit still doesn't help. What is "the workspace of the plugin" and how is it different from "the current workspace?" I'm

Comment: The workspace of the plugin is different than the one of the eclipse you are running from. The above URL works when running in regular eclipse, but in a plugin - it brings the workspace of the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to get the path of current running class - and by the way to get the path of the current workspace. (Not the workspace of the plugin)

```
 URL location = Current_class.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
 System.out.println(location.getFile());
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your own question, or a comment? It doesn't make any sense either.

Comment: The location of the current class is not an Eclipse workspace.